# Excel Data Mapping (similar to a join or where clause)

Tags: excel, function, data-binding

I have an excel workbook that has 2 sheets.
One sheet has 580 rows, the other has 187.

I have a list of names that will need to be mapped to the appropriate column based on a common column in both sheets.

Column D in sheet 1 and Column B in sheet 2 both contain "program names"
Column A in Sheet 2 contains text about certain programs, but not all programs have text.

I need to get the program text for 'Sheet2'!A2:A187 into 'Sheet1' Column C.

Basically the logic would look like this:

> Find Program Text 'Sheet2'!A2:A187
>
> WHERE
>
> 'Sheet1':D(current row) = 'Sheet2'!B2:b187

I'm just not exactly sure how to do it in excel.  I tried LOOKUP, but that didnt seem to do what I wanted exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have a header in the first row of each sheet.
Enter this formula in cell C2 of Sheet1 and drag down the bottom right corner of the cell to replicate the formula in all relevant rows of column C.

```
=IFNA(OFFSET(Sheet2!$A$1,MATCH(D2,Sheet2!B$2:B$187,0),0),"")
```

The `MATCH` function finds the contents of cell D2 in your desired range on sheet2 (you could make that a named range).  The 0 for the third `MATCH` parameter means the found value in the range must be identical to the first parameter (in this case, D2's value).  The `MATCH` returns the relative position of the matching cell from the start of the range, which is then used as the row offset from `Sheet2!$A$1` (the 0 in the OFFSET function second parameter means no change from column A).  The dollar signs (e.g., `$A` or `$1`) mean absolute row or absolute column, so when you copy the formula they are not changed in the destination cell.  The `IFNA` is used to make the cell value blank if the lookup did not find a match (`#N/A`).

The problem might be easier to solve with a `VLOOKUP` if you could swap columns A and B in Sheet2 so the lookup value is in the first column, but that changes the problem rather than answering your actual question.

Comment: Thanks!  It works great, except I had to remove the IFNA function. I was just getting #NAME? in all the fields.  Not sure why, but once I removed that it works perfectly.  Thank you so much, and for explaining it so well!

Comment: IFNA() was added in Excel 2013.  You can use IFERROR() here instead, if you have at least Excel 2007 (IFERROR is generic for any error, whereas IFNA is a specific type of error).  Otherwise, use a combination of IF() and ISERROR().